# SQL query Parent-child distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have a pair of SQL server tables.

P contains id and name.
PR contains id, interestrate, tiernumber, fromdate, todate and P.id. PR may contain many rows listed per p.id / tier. (tiers are a list of rates a product may have in any given date period.)

eg: Product 1 tier 1 starts 1/1/2008 to 1/1/2009 and has 6 rates shown 1 row per rate. Product 1 tier 2 starts 1/2/2009 etc etc etc

I need a view on this that shows the P.name and the PR.tiernumber and dates... BUT I want only one row to represent the tier.

This is easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ID, P.PRODUCTCODE, P.PRODUCTNAME, PR.TIERNO, 
  PR.FROMDATE, PR.TODATE, PR.PRODUCTID
FROM dbo.PRODUCTRATE AS PR INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCT AS P 
  ON P.ID = PR.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY P.ID DESC
```

This gives me the exact right data... However: this disallows me to see the PR.ID as that would negate the distinct.

I need to limit the resultset because the user needs to just see just a list of tiers, I need to see the PR.ID displaying all of the data.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to see the PR.ID"? WHICH PR.ID, since there are many per row, you can only show one. Either you have a row per P.ID / Tier, or per PR.ID.

Comment: Sorry - I need to return to an application a unique ID. The user wants to see all of the product's tiers and then wants to be able to select one to be more fully populated on screen. I need to find the tier number of the item selected and then use that to fetch the rest of the data... but the application can only give me the tier number if it has the unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.ID, P.ACUPRODUCTCODE, P.PRODUCTNAME, PR.TIERNO, 
  PR.FROMDATE, PR.TODATE, PR.PRODUCTID, MIN(PR.ID)
FROM dbo.PRODUCTRATE AS PR INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCT AS P 
  ON P.ID = PR.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.ACUPRODUCTCODE, P.PRODUCTNAME, PR.TIERNO, 
  PR.FROMDATE, PR.TODATE, PR.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY P.ID DESC
```

Ought to do the job.  GROUP BY in place of DISTINCT, with a summary function (MIN) to get a particular value back for the PR.ID.

Comment: Yes this returns a particular PR.ID value, but it's not clear from the OP's question *which* PR.ID value he needs (it might not be the MIN).  Maybe he will clarify.

Comment: I thought MIN made a little more sense than SUM in this case.  ;-)

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentleman. Just tried this and it works wonderfully. Thank you very much.

Comment: Bill, I just need one ID with this tiernumber, as then I fetch the data using this tiernumber.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to accomplish two different things with the same query, which doesn't make sense. Either you want a list of product/tier/date information or you want a list of interest rates.

If you want to pick a particular PR.ID to go with your data then you need to decide on what the rule is for that - what determines which ID you want to get back?

Comment: Tom, thank you. Yes I am limited by the application. What I am doing is getting a view to restrict the options to the user so that they just see that a product has had 5 tiers. When they decide to view an historic tier, they select the one option and then I fetch all rates for that tier... I need to offer the application a unique ID so that it can give it back to me so I can run the next fetch.